# Почему для регрессионной модели не строится график qqPlot в R?

Tags: r

Мне необходимо сделать подгонку регрессионной модели в виде полинома первой степени и проверить остатки на нормальность. Для этого я написал следующий код (различные другие тесты и построения графиков данных не вижу смысла показывать) в RStudio:

```
tableM2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Documents/m2reall.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
dateIndex <- seq_along(tableM2$Value)
fit1 <- lm(valueM2 ~ dateIndex, data = tableM2)
qqPlot(fit1)
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Error in qqPlot(fit1) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

Этой ошибки можно избежать, если в качестве аргумента принять остатки модели:

```
qqPlot(resid(fit1))
```

В таком случае я получаю почти то, что мне нужно: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но без 95% доверительных интервалов. Я не понимаю, почему не работает первый вариант функции qqPlot, потому что в учебнике Кабакова функцию используют в таком виде, и не понимаю, почему не строятся доверительные интервалы во втором случае.
Буду благодарен, если поможете)

UPD1. Чтобы было понятнее, что я хочу получить, прикреплю пример из учебника Кабакова "R в действии"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы пробовали такое выражение? `qqnorm(resid(fit1))`

Comment: Да, получается точно то же, что и на скриншоте, который я прикрепил, за исключением подписей графика и осей

Comment: Покажите свои данные, скорее всего проблема в них.